# Creating conda environment cause huge incompatible error with each other

Tags: anaconda

I'm trying to create a anaconda environment of computer vision project by using environment.yaml installation. But it fails on my computer. It is a huge compatible error. I want to install clean env.

The project https://github.com/zju3dv/NeuralRecon

My computer

- Linux 20.04
- nvidia-driver 510.47.03
- cuda 11.0
- cudnn 8.2.1

The environment.yaml

```
name: neucon
channels:
  # You can use the TUNA mirror to speed up the installation if you are in mainland China.
  # - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/pytorch
  - pytorch
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.7.9
  - pytorch=1.7.0
  - torchvision=0.10.0
  - cudatoolkit=11.6
  - ipython
  - tqdm
  - numba
  - sparsehash  # dependency for torchsparse
  - pip
  - pip:
    - -r requirements.txt
    - git+https://github.com/mit-han-lab/torchsparse.git
```

(base) ict-526@:~/NeuralRecon$ conda env create -f environment.yaml

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: / 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
Examining conflict for numba cudatoolkit torchvision python sparsehash: : 15it [00Examining conflict for cudatoolkit pytorch torchvision: : 15it [00:25,  1.85s/it] 
failed                                                                           
Solving environment: - 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
Examining conflict for numba cudatoolkit torchvision python sparsehash: : 15it [00Examining conflict for cudatoolkit pytorch torchvision: : 15it [00:26,  1.93s/it] 
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:
    
Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package tzdata conflicts for:
pip -> python[version='>=3.7'] -> tzdata
torchvision=0.10.0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tzdata
numba -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> tzdata
tqdm -> python[version='>=2.7'] -> tzdata
ipython -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> tzdata

Package six conflicts for:
ipython -> prompt-toolkit[version='>=2.0.0,<3.1.0,!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1'] -> six[version='>=1.13.0|>=1.9.0']
numba -> singledispatch -> six

Package expat conflicts for:
python=3.7.9 -> pypy3.7=7.3.3 -> expat[version='>=2.2.9,<3.0.0a0']
ipython -> pypy3.7[version='>=7.3.7'] -> expat[version='>=2.2.9,<3.0.0a0|>=2.3.0,<3.0a0|>=2.4.1,<3.0a0']

Package libgcc-ng conflicts for:
python=3.7.9 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0|>=9.3.0']
torchvision=0.10.0 -> cudatoolkit[version='>=11.1,<11.2'] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=9.3.0|>=9.4.0|>=7.3.0|>=7.2.0|>=4.9|>=8.4.0|>=3.0|>=5.4.0']
ipython -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=4.9|>=7.3.0|>=7.5.0|>=9.4.0|>=9.3.0|>=7.2.0']
torchvision=0.10.0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0']
python=3.7.9 -> libffi[version='>=3.3,<3.4.0a0'] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=7.5.0|>=9.4.0|>=7.2.0|>=4.9']
pip -> python[version='>=3.7'] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=4.9|>=7.3.0|>=7.5.0|>=9.4.0|>=9.3.0|>=7.2.0']
cudatoolkit=11.6 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.4.0']
numba -> numpy[version='>=1.21.5,<2.0a0'] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0']
pytorch=1.7.0 -> blas=[build=mkl] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=7.2.0|>=7.3.0|>=7.5.0|>=9.3.0|>=9.4.0|>=4.9']
sparsehash -> libgcc-ng[version='>=4.9|>=7.3.0|>=9.3.0']
tqdm -> python[version='>=2.7'] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=4.9|>=7.3.0|>=7.5.0|>=9.4.0|>=9.3.0|>=7.2.0']
numba -> libgcc-ng[version='>=4.9|>=7.3.0|>=7.5.0|>=9.4.0|>=9.3.0|>=7.2.0']

Package libnsl conflicts for:
tqdm -> python[version='>=2.7'] -> libnsl[version='>=2.0.0,<2.1.0a0']
ipython -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> libnsl[version='>=2.0.0,<2.1.0a0']
pip -> python[version='>=3.7'] -> libnsl[version='>=2.0.0,<2.1.0a0']
pytorch=1.7.0 -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> libnsl[version='>=2.0.0,<2.1.0a0']
torchvision=0.10.0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> libnsl[version='>=2.0.0,<2.1.0a0']
numba -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> libnsl[version='>=2.0.0,<2.1.0a0']

Package typing_extensions conflicts for:
pytorch=1.7.0 -> typing_extensions
torchvision=0.10.0 -> pytorch==1.9.0 -> typing_extensions
ipython -> black -> typing_extensions[version='>=3.10,!=3.10.0.1|>=3.7.4']

Package ca-certificates conflicts for:
tqdm -> python[version='>=2.7'] -> ca-certificates
ipython -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
numba -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
pip -> python -> ca-certificates
python=3.7.9 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a'] -> ca-certificates

Package mkl conflicts for:
pytorch=1.7.0 -> mkl[version='>=2018']
pytorch=1.7.0 -> blas=[build=mkl] -> mkl[version='>=2018.0.0,<2019.0a0|>=2018.0.1,<2019.0a0|>=2018.0.2,<2019.0a0|>=2018.0.3,<2019.0a0|>=2019.1,<2021.0a0|>=2019.3,<2021.0a0|>=2019.4,<2020.0a0|>=2019.4,<2021.0a0|>=2021.2.0,<2022.0a0|>=2021.3.0,<2022.0a0|>=2021.4.0,<2022.0a0']

Package numpy-base conflicts for:
torchvision=0.10.0 -> numpy[version='>=1.18.5,<2.0a0'] -> numpy-base[version='1.18.5.*|1.19.1|1.19.1|1.19.1|1.19.1|1.19.1|1.19.1|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.21.2',build='py38hfa32c7d_0|py36h75fe3a5_0|py37h75fe3a5_0|py38hfa32c7d_0|py39h0f7b65f_0|py37h34387ca_0|py38h34387ca_0|py39h7d8b39e_0|py38he2ba247_0|py38hfae3a4d_0|py38h74d4b33_0|py38h39b7dee_0|py38h79a1101_0|py39h79a1101_0|py37h79a1101_0|py310h2b8c604_0|py310h79a1101_0|py38h2b8c604_0|py39h2b8c604_0|py37h2b8c604_0|py39h39b7dee_0|py37h39b7dee_0|py39h74d4b33_0|py37h74d4b33_0|py39hfae3a4d_0|py37he2ba247_0|py37hfae3a4d_0|py39he2ba247_0|py38h7d8b39e_0|py39h34387ca_0|py37h7d8b39e_0|py39h2ae0177_0|py36hfa32c7d_0|py36h75fe3a5_0|py38h75fe3a5_0|py37hfa32c7d_0|py37h75fe3a5_0|py36hfa32c7d_0|py38h75fe3a5_0|py37hfa32c7d_0']
numba -> numpy[version='>=1.18.5,<2.0a0'] -> numpy-base[version='1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.17.0|1.17.0|1.17.0|1.17.0|1.17.2.*|1.17.3.*|1.17.4.*|1.18.1.*|1.18.5.*|1.19.1|1.19.1|1.19.1|1.19.1|1.19.1|1.19.1|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.21.2|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|>=1.9.3,<2.0a0',build='py27h2b20989_6|py37h2b20989_6|py27hdbf6ddf_6|py36hdbf6ddf_7|py35h2b20989_7|py37hdbf6ddf_7|py27h2b20989_7|py36hdbf6ddf_7|py37hdbf6ddf_7|py36hdbf6ddf_8|py37hdbf6ddf_8|py27h2b20989_8|py35hdbf6ddf_8|py35h2b20989_8|py37h7cdd4dd_9|py37h3dfced4_9|py36h3dfced4_9|py36h81de0dd_9|py37h81de0dd_9|py27h74e8950_9|py35h81de0dd_9|py37h74e8950_10|py35h74e8950_10|py27h74e8950_10|py37h81de0dd_10|py35h81de0dd_10|py37h2f8d375_10|py36h2f8d375_10|py27h2f8d375_10|py35h2f8d375_10|py27h2f8d375_12|py36h2f8d375_12|py27hde5b4d6_12|py37hde5b4d6_12|py36hde5b4d6_12|py38hde5b4d6_12|py38h2f8d375_12|py36h0ea5e3f_1|py35h0ea5e3f_1|py27h9be14a7_1|py35h9be14a7_1|py36h2b20989_0|py35h2b20989_0|py36hdbf6ddf_0|py36h2b20989_0|py37h2b20989_1|py27hdbf6ddf_1|py36hdbf6ddf_1|py37hdbf6ddf_1|py27h2b20989_1|py27h2b20989_2|py36h2b20989_2|py27hdbf6ddf_2|py27hdbf6ddf_3|py27h2b20989_4|py27hdbf6ddf_4|py36h2b20989_4|py35h2b20989_4|py35h2f8d375_4|py36h2f8d375_4|py37h81de0dd_4|py36h81de0dd_4|py36h2f8d375_5|py37hde5b4d6_5|py27h7cdd4dd_0|py37h7cdd4dd_0|py35h7cdd4dd_0|py36h3dfced4_0|py35h3dfced4_0|py35h74e8950_0|py27h74e8950_0|py36h74e8950_0|py37h74e8950_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py36h81de0dd_1|py37h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py36h81de0dd_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py37h2f8d375_1|py36hde5b4d6_1|py36h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py36hde5b4d6_1|py27hde5b4d6_1|py37h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py39hfb011de_1|py39h76555f2_1|py39h41b4c56_3|py38h41b4c56_3|py37h41b4c56_3|py36hdc34a94_3|py38hdc34a94_3|py39hdc34a94_3|py37hdc34a94_3|py36h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py38hfa32c7d_0|py36h75fe3a5_0|py37h75fe3a5_0|py38hfa32c7d_0|py39h0f7b65f_0|py37h34387ca_0|py38h34387ca_0|py39h7d8b39e_0|py38he2ba247_0|py38hfae3a4d_0|py38h74d4b33_0|py38h39b7dee_0|py38h79a1101_0|py39h79a1101_0|py37h79a1101_0|py310h2b8c604_0|py310h79a1101_0|py38h2b8c604_0|py39h2b8c604_0|py37h2b8c604_0|py39h39b7dee_0|py37h39b7dee_0|py39h74d4b33_0|py37h74d4b33_0|py39hfae3a4d_0|py37he2ba247_0|py37hfae3a4d_0|py39he2ba247_0|py38h7d8b39e_0|py39h34387ca_0|py37h7d8b39e_0|py39h2ae0177_0|py36hfa32c7d_0|py36h75fe3a5_0|py38h75fe3a5_0|py37hfa32c7d_0|py37h75fe3a5_0|py36hfa32c7d_0|py38h75fe3a5_0|py37hfa32c7d_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py36h41b4c56_3|py38hde5b4d6_0|py38h2f8d375_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_1|py36h2f8d375_1|py37h2f8d375_1|py27h2f8d375_1|py36hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py27hde5b4d6_1|py37hde5b4d6_1|py36h2f8d375_1|py27h2f8d375_1|py27h2f8d375_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py27h81de0dd_0|py37h81de0dd_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py37h81de0dd_0|py36h81de0dd_0|py27h81de0dd_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_1|py37h81de0dd_1|py27h81de0dd_1|py27h2f8d375_1|py36h2f8d375_1|py36h81de0dd_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py35h2f8d375_0|py35h81de0dd_0|py27h81de0dd_0|py37h81de0dd_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py35h2f8d375_0|py35h81de0dd_0|py37h81de0dd_0|py27h81de0dd_0|py36h81de0dd_0|py37h3dfced4_0|py27h3dfced4_0|py36h7cdd4dd_0|py36hde5b4d6_5|py27hde5b4d6_5|py27h2f8d375_5|py37h2f8d375_5|py38hde5b4d6_4|py38h2f8d375_4|py35h81de0dd_4|py27h2f8d375_4|py27h81de0dd_4|py37h2f8d375_4|py35hdbf6ddf_4|py36hdbf6ddf_4|py37hdbf6ddf_4|py37h2b20989_4|py27h2b20989_3|py36hdbf6ddf_3|py37hdbf6ddf_3|py37h2b20989_3|py36h2b20989_3|py36hdbf6ddf_2|py37hdbf6ddf_2|py37h2b20989_2|py36h2b20989_1|py35hdbf6ddf_0|py27hdbf6ddf_0|py36hdbf6ddf_0|py27h2b20989_0|py35hdbf6ddf_0|py27hdbf6ddf_0|py27h2b20989_0|py36h9be14a7_1|py27h0ea5e3f_1|py37h2f8d375_12|py27hde5b4d6_11|py37hde5b4d6_11|py36hde5b4d6_11|py36h2f8d375_11|py27h2f8d375_11|py37h2f8d375_11|py36h81de0dd_10|py27h81de0dd_10|py36h74e8950_10|py27h81de0dd_9|py36h74e8950_9|py37h74e8950_9|py35h74e8950_9|py27h3dfced4_9|py35h3dfced4_9|py27h7cdd4dd_9|py35h7cdd4dd_9|py36h7cdd4dd_9|py27hdbf6ddf_8|py37h2b20989_8|py36h2b20989_8|py27hdbf6ddf_7|py36h2b20989_7|py37h2b20989_7|py37h2b20989_7|py35hdbf6ddf_7|py36h2b20989_7|py27h2b20989_7|py27hdbf6ddf_7|py36hdbf6ddf_6|py37hdbf6ddf_6|py36h2b20989_6']
pytorch=1.7.0 -> numpy[version='>=1.11'] -> numpy-base[version='1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.17.0|1.17.0|1.17.0|1.17.0|1.17.2.*|1.17.3.*|1.17.4.*|1.18.1.*|1.18.5.*|1.19.1|1.19.1|1.19.1|1.19.1|1.19.1|1.19.1|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.21.2',build='py27h2b20989_7|py36hdbf6ddf_7|py37hdbf6ddf_7|py36hdbf6ddf_8|py37hdbf6ddf_8|py27h2b20989_8|py35hdbf6ddf_8|py35h2b20989_8|py37h7cdd4dd_9|py37h3dfced4_9|py36h3dfced4_9|py36h81de0dd_9|py37h81de0dd_9|py27h74e8950_9|py35h81de0dd_9|py37h74e8950_10|py35h74e8950_10|py27h74e8950_10|py37h81de0dd_10|py35h81de0dd_10|py37h2f8d375_10|py36h2f8d375_10|py27h2f8d375_10|py35h2f8d375_10|py27h2f8d375_12|py36h2f8d375_12|py27hde5b4d6_12|py37hde5b4d6_12|py36hde5b4d6_12|py38hde5b4d6_12|py38h2f8d375_12|py36h0ea5e3f_1|py35h0ea5e3f_1|py27h9be14a7_1|py35h9be14a7_1|py36h2b20989_0|py35h2b20989_0|py36hdbf6ddf_0|py36h2b20989_0|py37h2b20989_1|py27hdbf6ddf_1|py36hdbf6ddf_1|py37hdbf6ddf_1|py27h2b20989_1|py27h2b20989_2|py36h2b20989_2|py27hdbf6ddf_2|py27hdbf6ddf_3|py27h2b20989_4|py27hdbf6ddf_4|py36h2b20989_4|py35h2b20989_4|py35h2f8d375_4|py36h2f8d375_4|py37h81de0dd_4|py36h81de0dd_4|py36h2f8d375_5|py37hde5b4d6_5|py27h7cdd4dd_0|py37h7cdd4dd_0|py35h7cdd4dd_0|py36h3dfced4_0|py35h3dfced4_0|py35h74e8950_0|py27h74e8950_0|py36h74e8950_0|py37h74e8950_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py36h81de0dd_1|py37h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py36h81de0dd_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py37h2f8d375_1|py36hde5b4d6_1|py36h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py36hde5b4d6_1|py27hde5b4d6_1|py37h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py39hfb011de_1|py39h76555f2_1|py39h41b4c56_3|py38h41b4c56_3|py37h41b4c56_3|py36hdc34a94_3|py38hdc34a94_3|py39hdc34a94_3|py37hdc34a94_3|py36h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py38hfa32c7d_0|py36h75fe3a5_0|py37h75fe3a5_0|py38hfa32c7d_0|py39h0f7b65f_0|py37h34387ca_0|py38h34387ca_0|py39h7d8b39e_0|py38he2ba247_0|py38hfae3a4d_0|py38h74d4b33_0|py38h39b7dee_0|py38h79a1101_0|py39h79a1101_0|py37h79a1101_0|py310h2b8c604_0|py310h79a1101_0|py38h2b8c604_0|py39h2b8c604_0|py37h2b8c604_0|py39h39b7dee_0|py37h39b7dee_0|py39h74d4b33_0|py37h74d4b33_0|py39hfae3a4d_0|py37he2ba247_0|py37hfae3a4d_0|py39he2ba247_0|py38h7d8b39e_0|py39h34387ca_0|py37h7d8b39e_0|py39h2ae0177_0|py36hfa32c7d_0|py36h75fe3a5_0|py38h75fe3a5_0|py37hfa32c7d_0|py37h75fe3a5_0|py36hfa32c7d_0|py38h75fe3a5_0|py37hfa32c7d_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py36h41b4c56_3|py38hde5b4d6_0|py38h2f8d375_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_1|py36h2f8d375_1|py37h2f8d375_1|py27h2f8d375_1|py36hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py27hde5b4d6_1|py37hde5b4d6_1|py36h2f8d375_1|py27h2f8d375_1|py27h2f8d375_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py27h81de0dd_0|py37h81de0dd_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py37h81de0dd_0|py36h81de0dd_0|py27h81de0dd_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_1|py37h81de0dd_1|py27h81de0dd_1|py27h2f8d375_1|py36h2f8d375_1|py36h81de0dd_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py35h2f8d375_0|py35h81de0dd_0|py27h81de0dd_0|py37h81de0dd_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py35h2f8d375_0|py35h81de0dd_0|py37h81de0dd_0|py27h81de0dd_0|py36h81de0dd_0|py37h3dfced4_0|py27h3dfced4_0|py36h7cdd4dd_0|py36hde5b4d6_5|py27hde5b4d6_5|py27h2f8d375_5|py37h2f8d375_5|py38hde5b4d6_4|py38h2f8d375_4|py35h81de0dd_4|py27h2f8d375_4|py27h81de0dd_4|py37h2f8d375_4|py35hdbf6ddf_4|py36hdbf6ddf_4|py37hdbf6ddf_4|py37h2b20989_4|py27h2b20989_3|py36hdbf6ddf_3|py37hdbf6ddf_3|py37h2b20989_3|py36h2b20989_3|py36hdbf6ddf_2|py37hdbf6ddf_2|py37h2b20989_2|py36h2b20989_1|py35hdbf6ddf_0|py27hdbf6ddf_0|py36hdbf6ddf_0|py27h2b20989_0|py35hdbf6ddf_0|py27hdbf6ddf_0|py27h2b20989_0|py36h9be14a7_1|py27h0ea5e3f_1|py37h2f8d375_12|py27hde5b4d6_11|py37hde5b4d6_11|py36hde5b4d6_11|py36h2f8d375_11|py27h2f8d375_11|py37h2f8d375_11|py36h81de0dd_10|py27h81de0dd_10|py36h74e8950_10|py27h81de0dd_9|py36h74e8950_9|py37h74e8950_9|py35h74e8950_9|py27h3dfced4_9|py35h3dfced4_9|py27h7cdd4dd_9|py35h7cdd4dd_9|py36h7cdd4dd_9|py27hdbf6ddf_8|py37h2b20989_8|py36h2b20989_8|py27hdbf6ddf_7|py36h2b20989_7|py37h2b20989_7']

Package cudatoolkit conflicts for:
cudatoolkit=11.6
torchvision=0.10.0 -> cudatoolkit[version='10.2|10.2.*|11.0|11.0.*|11.1|11.1.*|>=10.2,<10.3|>=11.1,<11.2|>=11.2,<12.0a0']
torchvision=0.10.0 -> cudnn[version='>=8.2.1.32,<9.0a0'] -> cudatoolkit[version='10.0.*|10.0|10.0.*|10.1|10.1.*|10.2.*|11.*|>=11.5,<11.6|>=11.3,<11.4|>=11.2,<12|>=10.1,<10.2|>=11.0,<11.1|>=9.2,<9.3|9.2|9.2.*|>=10.0,<10.1|>=10.1.243,<10.2.0a0|>=9.2,<9.3.0a0|>=10.0.130,<10.1.0a0|9.2.*|>=9.0,<9.1|>=9.0,<9.1.0a0|>=8.0,<8.1|>=8.0,<8.1.0a0|8.*|9.*|9.0.*|8.0.*|7.5.*']
pytorch=1.7.0 -> cudatoolkit[version='>=10.1,<10.2|>=11.0,<11.1|>=10.2,<10.3|>=9.2,<9.3']

Package pytorch conflicts for:
torchvision=0.10.0 -> pytorch==1.9.0
pytorch=1.7.0
torchvision=0.10.0 -> pytorch-gpu -> pytorch[version='1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.0|1.10.1|1.10.1|1.10.1|1.10.1|1.10.1|1.10.1|1.10.1|1.10.1|1.10.1|1.10.1|1.10.1|1.10.1|1.10.2|1.9.1|1.9.1|1.9.1|1.9.1|1.9.1|1.9.1|1.9.1|1.9.1|1.9.1|1.9.1|1.9.1|1.9.1|1.9.1|1.9.1|1.9.1|1.9.1|1.9.0|1.9.0|1.9.0|1.9.0|1.9.0|1.9.0|1.9.0|1.9.0|1.9.0|1.9.0|1.9.0|1.9.0|1.9.0|1.9.0|1.9.0|1.9.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.7.1|1.7.1|1.7.1|1.7.1|1.7.1|1.7.1|1.7.1|1.7.1|1.7.1|1.7.1|1.7.1|1.7.1|1.7.1|1.7.1|1.7.1|1.7.1|1.6.0|1.6.0|1.6.0|1.6.0|1.6.0|1.6.0|1.6.0|1.6.0|1.6.0|1.6.0|1.6.0|1.6.0|1.6.0|1.6.0|1.6.0|1.6.0|1.3.1.*|1.2.0.*|1.10.2|1.10.2|1.10.2|1.10.2|1.10.2|1.10.2|1.10.1|1.10.1|1.10.1|1.9.1|1.9.1|1.9.1|1.9.1|1.9.0|1.9.0|1.9.0|1.9.0|1.9.0|1.9.0|1.9.0|1.9.0|1.9.0|1.9.0|1.9.0|1.9.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.8.0|1.7.1|1.7.1|1.7.1|1.7.1|1.7.1|1.7.1|1.7.1|1.7.1|1.6.0|1.6.0|1.6.0|1.6',build='cpu_py37hf1c21f6_1|cpu_py38h36eccb8_1|cpu_py37hf1c21f6_2|cpu_py37hafa7651_0|cpu_py36h2d15a6b_1|cpu_py36h95c28ec_2|cpu_py37hd5260e0_2|cpu_py38h91ab35c_2|cpu_py39hfbcbfe4_2|cpu_py38h91ab35c_3|cpu_py36h95c28ec_3|cpu_py38h91ab35c_0|cpu_py39hfbcbfe4_0|cpu_py37hd5260e0_0|cpu_py36h3564fbe_1|cpu_py37hff829bd_1|cpu_py39h818de69_1|cpu_py39h818de69_2|cpu_py38h4bbe6ce_2|cpu_py37hf3cc979_3|cpu_py39hc5866cc_3|cpu_py38h1ee18c8_3|cpu_py38hb2150b6_0|cpu_py39h5e9ed0b_0|cpu_py39h5e9ed0b_0|cpu_py38hb2150b6_0|cpu_py38hb2150b6_1|cpu_py37h76afcab_1|cpu_py39h5e9ed0b_1|cuda92py36h7ecc001_1|cuda100py37h50b9e00_1|cuda92py39hde86683_1|cuda101py39h41d04a9_1|cuda92py36h7ecc001_1|cuda102py36h8620ce9_1|cuda100py36hd82b6f9_1|cuda102py37h4d98c68_1|cuda100py37h50b9e00_1|cuda101py38h2499a06_1|cuda92py39hde86683_1|cuda100py39h2b73809_1|cuda101py39h41d04a9_1|cuda102py36hf4eb8d7_0|cuda102py37h4454d97_0|cuda110py37h5fb8b0b_0|cuda110py39hbc72f07_0|cuda112py38h3bc52bc_1|cuda112py39h716d6ff_1|cuda111py36h3cb1cac_1|cuda111py37h50e976f_1|cuda111py39hc274426_1|cuda102py36he3537ca_1|cuda102py38hf03d9dd_1|cuda110py36h768fbb7_1|cuda112py39hbeb36f3_1|cuda112py37hcb91bf2_1|cuda111py36hc5445e6_1|cuda110py37h00edf66_1|cuda102py37h92fd811_1|cuda111py37h78388d7_1|cuda110py39hd6acddb_1|cuda112py38h3d13190_1|cuda112py38h4f2a933_3|cuda112py36h36e649e_3|cuda111py39hb4a4491_3|cuda111py37he371307_3|cuda111py38h2f85826_3|cuda102py36h3d4679f_3|cuda102py37h98b7ee3_3|cuda102py39h2fcd037_3|cuda110py37h4a33b93_3|cuda110py39h5cf7045_3|cuda102py39h2fcd037_0|cuda112py37h3bec1eb_0|cuda111py37he371307_0|cuda111py38h2f85826_0|cuda102py38ha031fbe_0|cuda112py38h4f2a933_0|cuda112py39h4e14dd4_0|cuda111py39hb4a4491_0|cuda112py39h3ad47f5_1|cuda110py38h68479e5_1|cuda111py39h7295ad4_1|cuda102py39h06ffc54_1|cuda112py38h6425f36_0|cuda111py38hc64aeea_0|cuda111py39h930882a_0|cuda110py38hf0a79ac_0|cuda110py37h4121e64_0|cuda112py39h4de5995_0|cuda112py38h6425f36_0|cuda111py39h930882a_0|cuda111py37hc0ce48b_0|cuda110py37h4121e64_1|cuda111py38hc64aeea_1|cuda102py38h9fb240c_1|cuda110py39he47eb21_1|cuda111py39h930882a_1|cuda112py39h4de5995_1|cuda102py39hfe0cb5b_1|cuda112py38h6425f36_1|cuda110py38hf0a79ac_1|cuda112py37hc1ee5ce_1|cuda111py37hc0ce48b_1|cuda102py37hc804c4d_1|cuda102py38h9fb240c_0|cuda102py39hfe0cb5b_0|cuda102py37hc804c4d_0|cuda110py37h4121e64_0|cuda110py39he47eb21_0|cuda110py38hf0a79ac_0|cuda111py38hc64aeea_0|cuda112py37hc1ee5ce_0|cuda110py39he47eb21_0|cuda111py37hc0ce48b_0|cuda112py37hc1ee5ce_0|cuda112py39h4de5995_0|cuda102py39hfe0cb5b_0|cuda102py37hc804c4d_0|cuda102py38h9fb240c_0|cuda102py37h689c94d_1|cuda111py37h07fa5b8_1|cuda110py37h7b7832c_1|cuda110py39h423d6c6_1|cuda111py38h9575ccd_1|cuda102py38h17946ce_1|cuda112py38had345c2_1|cuda112py37haf94430_1|cuda110py39h5cf7045_0|cuda102py37h98b7ee3_0|cuda110py37h4a33b93_0|cuda110py38hf84197b_0|cuda110py38hf84197b_3|cuda110py36he570edd_3|cuda102py38ha031fbe_3|cuda112py37h3bec1eb_3|cuda112py39h4e14dd4_3|cuda111py36h8a2106e_3|cuda112py36h755b813_1|cuda110py38hc2289b8_1|cuda102py39h9bf10ef_1|cuda111py38h5169e65_1|cuda112py37h946b90b_1|cuda112py36h5fea6e2_1|cuda111py39h37e5b68_1|cuda111py38he2736ed_1|cuda110py38h65e529b_0|cuda110py36h7ef7e1d_0|cuda102py39hf89b2ab_0|cuda102py38h540557e_0|cuda102py38h9f8c3ab_1|cuda101py36h42dc283_1|cuda100py38h679e3f5_1|cuda92py38hb6ed0dd_1|cuda102py39h09d0254_1|cuda92py37hc3ec645_1|cuda101py37h7589291_1|cuda102py38h9f8c3ab_1|cuda100py39h2b73809_1|cuda102py39h09d0254_1|cuda100py38h679e3f5_1|cuda101py38h2499a06_1|cuda92py38hb6ed0dd_1|cuda101py37h7589291_1|cuda102py37h4d98c68_1|cuda92py37hc3ec645_1|cuda101py36h42dc283_1|cuda102py36h8620ce9_1|cuda100py36hd82b6f9_1|cpu_py37h76afcab_0|cpu_py37h76afcab_0|cpu_py39hc70245e_1|cpu_py38h7c5583f_1|cpu_py37h2761dfd_1|cpu_py38h1ee18c8_0|cpu_py37hf3cc979_0|cpu_py39hc5866cc_0|cpu_py36ha8b20dc_3|cpu_py37hb06efa0_2|cpu_py36h1c7b8ea_2|cpu_py38hfb3baa6_1|cpu_py36h95c28ec_0|cpu_py39hfbcbfe4_3|cpu_py37hd5260e0_3|cpu_py38hd248515_1|cpu_py39h0fbb4fb_1|cpu_py37ha70c682_1|cpu_py39h0fbb4fb_0|cpu_py38he614459_0|cpu_py36h2ecc29a_0|cpu_py38h36eccb8_2|cpu_py39h714fb45_2|cpu_py36h63cae03_2|cpu_py37hf1c21f6_1|cpu_py36h63cae03_1|cpu_py38h36eccb8_1|cpu_py39h714fb45_1|cpu_py36h63cae03_1']

Package wheel conflicts for:
python=3.7.9 -> pip -> wheel
pip -> wheel

Package certifi conflicts for:
pip -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26']
ipython -> setuptools[version='>=18.5'] -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26']
numba -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26']

Package setuptools conflicts for:
numba -> setuptools
ipython -> setuptools[version='>=18.5']
torchvision=0.10.0 -> pytorch -> setuptools[version='<59.6']
ipython -> pygments[version='>=2.4.0'] -> setuptools
python=3.7.9 -> pip -> setuptools
pip -> setuptools

Package _libgcc_mutex conflicts for:
torchvision=0.10.0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build='main|main|conda_forge']
numba -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.4.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build='main|main|conda_forge']
python=3.7.9 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build='main|main|conda_forge']
sparsehash -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build='main|main|conda_forge']
cudatoolkit=11.6 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.4.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex==0.1=conda_forge

Package pip conflicts for:
pytorch=1.7.0 -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> pip
pip
python=3.7.9 -> pip
numba -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> pip
torchvision=0.10.0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> pip
ipython -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> pip
tqdm -> python[version='>=2.7'] -> pip

Package _openmp_mutex conflicts for:
numba -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
sparsehash -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
pytorch=1.7.0 -> blas=[build=mkl] -> _openmp_mutex[version='*|>=4.5',build=*_llvm]
python=3.7.9 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
cudatoolkit=11.6 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.4.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
torchvision=0.10.0 -> pytorch==1.9.0 -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']

Package blas conflicts for:
pytorch=1.7.0 -> blas=[build=mkl]
pytorch=1.7.0 -> numpy[version='>=1.11'] -> blas[version='*|1.0|1.1|1.0',build='openblas|mkl|openblas|openblas']

Package pypy3.6 conflicts for:
ipython -> jedi[version='>=0.16'] -> pypy3.6[version='7.3.*|7.3.0.*|7.3.1.*|7.3.2.*|7.3.3.*|>=7.3.2']
ipython -> pypy3.6[version='>=7.3.1|>=7.3.3']

Package openblas conflicts for:
numba -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0'] -> openblas[version='0.2.18.*|0.2.18|0.2.18.*|0.2.19|0.2.19.*|0.2.20|0.2.20.*|>=0.2.20,<0.2.21.0a0|>=0.3.3,<0.3.4.0a0|>=0.2.15']
pytorch=1.7.0 -> numpy[version='>=1.11'] -> openblas[version='0.2.18.*|0.2.18|0.2.18.*|0.2.19|0.2.19.*|0.2.20|0.2.20.*|>=0.2.20,<0.2.21.0a0|>=0.3.3,<0.3.4.0a0|>=0.2.15']The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.31=0
  - cudatoolkit=11.6 -> __glibc[version='>=2.17,<3.0.a0']
  - numba -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - python=3.7.9 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - pytorch=1.7.0 -> cudatoolkit[version='>=11.0,<11.1'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17,<3.0.a0']
  - sparsehash -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - torchvision=0.10.0 -> __glibc[version='>=2.17|>=2.17,<3.0.a0']

Your installed version is: 2.31
```

Comment: Why have you changed the `environment.yaml` from the [version provided in the repo](https://github.com/zju3dv/NeuralRecon/blob/master/environment.yaml)?

Comment: I changed it because newer version will solved this problem. And I forgot it. Now I know I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have made manual changes to the `environment.yaml` that is provided in the [git that you linked](https://github.com/zju3dv/NeuralRecon/blob/master/environment.yaml). From the github (your changes highlighted):

```
name: neucon
channels:
  # You can use the TUNA mirror to speed up the installation if you are in mainland China.
  # - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/pytorch
  - pytorch
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.7.9
  - pytorch=1.6.0 #Changed by you
  - torchvision=0.7.0 #Changed by you
  - cudatoolkit=10.2 #Changed by you
  - ipython
  - tqdm
  - numba
  - sparsehash  # dependency for torchsparse
  - pip
  - pip:
    - -r requirements.txt
    - git+https://github.com/mit-han-lab/torchsparse.git
```

There is no guarantee that the file should be solvable with your manual changes and we see in your output that they are causing problems:

E.g.:

```
torchvision=0.10.0 -> cudatoolkit[version='>=11.1,<11.2']
torchvision=0.10.0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
```

Simply use the recommended environment file which works just fine.

Comment: I'd just add that historically the PyTorch channel only supports a limited subset of `cudatoolkit` versions, and v11.6 is not one of them. See actual supported versions in [the package build strings](https://anaconda.org/pytorch/pytorch/files). Moreover, even though they build some additional ones, [the current recommended versions](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#start-locally) are either 10.2 and 11.3

Comment: Thank you!!!!! You helped me a lot. I solved it now.